# React-table Select All Select Box

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

https://codesandbox.io/s/8x331yomp0

I'm trying to create a select all checkbox in my table. When I click the header checkbox, I want the other checkboxes to populate, as well.

I'm trying to do this with a selectAlll state value, but for whatever reason, this keeps coming back false the first time, so it is always opposite of what the value should be. Any chance someone knows what is wrong? I put the code sandbox up at the top, but here is my table code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import $ from "jquery";
import ReactTable from "react-table";
import "react-table/react-table.css";

const style = {
  container: {
    position: "relative"
  },

  refresh: {
    cursor: "pointer",
    width: "75px"
  }
};

class KKTable extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      timestamp: "",
      selectAll: false,
      data: [],
      checked: []
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange = () => {
    var selectAll = !this.state.selectAll;
    this.setState({ selectAll: selectAll });
    var checkedCopy = [];
    this.state.data.forEach(function(e, index) {
      checkedCopy.push(selectAll);
    });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const data2 = [
      { one: "hi0", two: "two0", three: "three0" },
      { one: "hi1", two: "two1", three: "three1" },
      { one: "hi2", two: "two2", three: "three2" },
      { one: "hi3", two: "two3", three: "three3" },
      { one: "hi4", two: "two4", three: "three4" },
      { one: "hi5", two: "two5", three: "three5" },
      { one: "hi6", two: "two6", three: "three6" },
      { one: "hi7", two: "two7", three: "three7" },
      { one: "hi8", two: "two8", three: "three8" }
    ];

    var checkedCopy = [];
    var selectAll = this.state.selectAll;
    data2.forEach(function(e, index) {
      checkedCopy.push(selectAll);
    });

    this.setState({
      data: data2,
      checked: checkedCopy,
      selectAll: false
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="container">
          <ReactTable
            data={this.state.data}
            filterable
            defaultFilterMethod={(filter, row) =>
              row[filter.id] !== undefined
                ? String(row[filter.id])
                    .toLowerCase()
                    .includes(filter.value.toLowerCase())
                : false
            }
            columns={[
              {
                Header: "One",
                accessor: "one"
              },
              {
                Header: <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.handleChange} />,
                Cell: row => (
                  <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    defaultChecked={this.state.checked[row.index]}
                  />
                ),
                sortable: false,
                filterable: false
              },
              {
                Header: "Two",
                accessor: "two"
              },
              {
                Header: "Three",
                accessor: "three"
              }
            ]}
            className="-striped "
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default KKTable;
```

Answer (score 12):

Figured it out. In case anyone needs the code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import $ from "jquery";
import ReactTable from "react-table";
import "react-table/react-table.css";

const style = {
  container: {
    position: "relative"
  },

  refresh: {
    cursor: "pointer",
    width: "75px"
  }
};

class KKTable extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      timestamp: "",
      selectAll: false,
      data: [],
      checked: []
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSingleCheckboxChange = this.handleSingleCheckboxChange.bind(
      this
    );
  }

  handleChange = () => {
    var selectAll = !this.state.selectAll;
    this.setState({ selectAll: selectAll });
    var checkedCopy = [];
    this.state.data.forEach(function(e, index) {
      checkedCopy.push(selectAll);
    });
    this.setState({
      checked: checkedCopy
    });
  };

  handleSingleCheckboxChange = index => {
    console.log(index);

    var checkedCopy = this.state.checked;
    checkedCopy[index] = !this.state.checked[index];
    if (checkedCopy[index] === false) {
      this.setState({ selectAll: false });
    }

    this.setState({
      checked: checkedCopy
    });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const data2 = [
      { one: "hi0", two: "two0", three: "three0" },
      { one: "hi1", two: "two1", three: "three1" },
      { one: "hi2", two: "two2", three: "three2" },
      { one: "hi3", two: "two3", three: "three3" },
      { one: "hi4", two: "two4", three: "three4" },
      { one: "hi5", two: "two5", three: "three5" },
      { one: "hi6", two: "two6", three: "three6" },
      { one: "hi7", two: "two7", three: "three7" },
      { one: "hi8", two: "two8", three: "three8" }
    ];

    var checkedCopy = [];
    var selectAll = this.state.selectAll;
    data2.forEach(function(e, index) {
      checkedCopy.push(selectAll);
    });

    this.setState({
      data: data2,
      checked: checkedCopy,
      selectAll: selectAll
    });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="container">
          <ReactTable
            data={this.state.data}
            filterable
            defaultFilterMethod={(filter, row) =>
              row[filter.id] !== undefined
                ? String(row[filter.id])
                    .toLowerCase()
                    .includes(filter.value.toLowerCase())
                : false
            }
            columns={[
              {
                Header: "One",
                accessor: "one"
              },
              {
                Header: (
                  <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    checked={this.state.selectAll}
                  />
                ),
                Cell: row => (
                  <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    defaultChecked={this.state.checked[row.index]}
                    checked={this.state.checked[row.index]}
                    onChange={() => this.handleSingleCheckboxChange(row.index)}
                  />
                ),
                sortable: false,
                filterable: false
              },
              {
                Header: "Two",
                accessor: "two"
              },
              {
                Header: "Three",
                accessor: "three"
              }
            ]}
            className="-striped "
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default KKTable;
```

Answer (score -1):

Where are you pulling the `filter.id` from in `row[filter.id] !== undefined`?

This may cause some issues with how the child items are then selected

Comment: It's just part of the react-table code for filters. I pass the row and filter to the function.